# how to add elements to front of 2d vector

Tags: c++, vector, 2d

I have a game that creates a random string of letters and then inputs it to a 2d vector. I was oringally using an array and it filled the array with random letters as it should, but the array was giving me some problems. My friend suggested a 2d array.

Here is the print function that gives me the error that actually causes a break in the program:

```
const vector<vector<char>>&  Board::get_board()
{
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    letters.insert(letters.begin(), 1, random_letter());
}

uppercase(letters);
random_shuffle(letters.begin(), letters.end());

int counter = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        board[0].push_back(letters[counter++]);

    }
}
```

I keep getting the array to fill the first row, but then it throws an exception. I'm not sure what the exception is, but when I try to move forward, it tells me the code exited with exception 0 and points to the board[][] line in the print method. I don't think the second vector is being filled. How can I do this? Should I make another temp vector, or use a pair method? I tried the pair method before without much success.

I just changed the 0 to i and indeed, that solved the issue. Thanks! I think that I was thinking the vector would just push to the front counter number of times, not that we had 2 dimensions where the board[i] set the row. Thanks again. Silly error.

Comment: When the debug assertion failed dialog comes up, it says:

C:\windows\sys32.....\visualk studio\12.0\vc\include\vector Line 1201

When I hit retry, it just says that my program has triggered an exception. It points to the board[][] line in Board::print.

Comment: do you have a suggestion to set the inner vector? I think you're right. that is why it is never getting past the j=0 row.

Comment: Piece of advice... you can edit your question to provide clarity or to correct mistakes you caught.

Comment: I have a feeling you may be back, lots of us do... for future reference, don't edit the question to thank us, you can use a comment. More importantly, use the upvote arrow and the accept checkbox on the answer, this is what will encourage people to answer you in the future. :) (I'm not super active on this site, but I do moderate on two others on the network, so I'm used to explaining this)

Answer (score 0):

Your vector isn't being populated correctly in your `get_board()` method:

```
board[0].push_back(letters[counter]);
```

You're always pushing back onto the first element, but then you use it with the expectation that the board vector has 4 entries in it with the `print()` method. You also never increment `counter` and so you always push back the same letter...

Okay, based on comments, you've said you fixed how populate to something more like?

```
int counter = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        board[i].push_back(letters[counter++]);
    }
}
```

I also don't see the point of the if statement in the `print()` method.

Comment: thanks, but i noticed right after posting. I changed it to increment in the brackets. The first row prints like it should. I still get the exception after the first row is printed, which is what was happening.

Comment: @user3076458 - What's the exception then? You might also want to fix up your question if that's not it. As it is, there's a trail of bugs in there.

Comment: I answered above. it never really gives one, just that it exited with code 0. it breaks at the Bpard::print - board[][] line

Comment: Thank you, John. That was left over from another implementation of printing that I decided to remove. I just forgot to take it out. Here's what I have now:


for (size_t j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
   board[0].push_back(letters[counter++]);
   
  }

Comment: @user3076458 - Your issue is board[0] instead of board[i] when populating it, as I noted at the start. You clearly don't have a second element in the outer vector.